# Can't execute a class function through a function pointer c++

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers

This might be retarded, and I've searched and tried many solutions but I always get errors.

```
class mainStateMachine;
typedef void (mainStateMachine::*StateProc)( EIndication input); 

class mainStateMachine
    {    
        public:
            StateProc currentState;
            int transition;
            void rotateUntilBlobsFound    ( EIndication input); 
          void clarifyImage             (EIndication input); 
        }
```

And then:

```
main()
{
    int input=0;
    StateProc BLA;
    mainStateMachine mainMachine;
    mainMachine.currentState=&mainStateMachine::rotateUntilBlobsFound; 

    BLA=mainMachine.currentState;

    BLA(input);
}
```

This doesnt work for some reason, tells me " must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in 'BLA (...)" but even when I do *BLA(input); it doesn't work.
I really don't understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: BLA requires a pointer to an instance

Comment: `mainMachine.*BLA` should work.

Comment: Yeah, that worked thanks a lot, now it seems obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BLA requires a pointer to an instance because member function pointers cannot be dereferenced (have their function called) directly by themselves. They must be called on behalf of some object, that then provides the "this" pointer for use by the member functions. how else you could do things affecting object implementation if function doesn't know on which object it operates.

So this is how you can call a method assigned to BLA:

```
(mainMachine.*BLA)( input);
```

You can also consider `boost::function` or `std::function` instead of raw pointers to ease operations, in example:

```
std::function< void(const mainStateMachine&, EIndication)> f_ptr = 
                                           &mainMachine::rotateUntilBlobsFound;
    const mainStateMachine foo;
    f_ptr( foo, EIndication());
```

[example](http://ideone.com/AF4vtd)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer!

Comment: I am at your service sir.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the other errors, such as no semicolon after the class definition and no return type on `main`, pointers to members need an object to operate on. You can provide one by using the pointer to member operator:

```
(mainMachine.*BLA)(input);
```

Being a pointer to a member function, all `BLA` contains is the address of a member function, not any object to use with it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked indeed. Yeah the other problems aren't really in the original program, I took the relevants parts and forgot that stuff. Thanks!

Comment: @user3742604, You would be wise to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in future questions. Something that people can take, paste into an editor, compile, and possibly fix.

Comment: I don't understand how BLA= &mainStateMachine::currentState; would work though, as BLA should be equal to the .currentState of the mainMachine object. How is that equivalent?

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast BLA = &mainStateMachine::currentState; is not correct as currentState is a pointer already

Comment: @bits_international, Sorry, I had in my mind that it was a member function. I'll change that.

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast sure, no problems

Comment: @user3742604, Sorry about the mixup. I should have gone back to the question code.